# Detect Apple Device Model

Tags: ios, objective-c, device

I need to detect if the device is an iPhone 5 or iPhone 5s.
I've searched the forum but I could not find any solution.

How I can do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this code in order to get current device model:

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>

+ (NSString *) deviceModel
{ 
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);

    NSString *deviceOriginalName = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *deviceFormattedName = deviceOriginalName;

    if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,1"])        deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 2G";                   //iPhone 2G
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone1,2"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 3G";              //iPhone 3G
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone2,1"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 3GS";             //iPhone 3GS
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,1"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 4";               //iPhone 4 - AT&T
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,2"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 4";               //iPhone 4 - Other carrier
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone3,3"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 4";               //iPhone 4 - Other carrier
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone4,1"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 4S";              //iPhone 4S
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,1"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 5";               //iPhone 5 (GSM)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,2"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 5";               //iPhone 5 (GSM+CDMA)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,3"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 5c";              //iPhone 5c (GSM)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone5,4"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 5c";              //iPhone 5c (GSM+CDMA)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,1"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 5s";              //iPhone 5s (GSM)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone6,2"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 5s";              //iPhone 5s (GSM+CDMA)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,1"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 6 Plus";          //iPhone 6+
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone7,2"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 6";               //iPhone 6
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 6S";              //iPhone 6S
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 6S Plus";         //iPhone 6S+
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,4"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone SE";              //iPhone SE
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,1"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 7";               //iPhone 7 (CDMA)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,3"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 7";               //iPhone 7 (GSM)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,2"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 7 Plus";          //iPhone 7 Plus (CDMA)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone9,4"])   deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 7 Plus";          //iPhone 7 Plus (GSM)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone10,1"])  deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 8";               //iPhone 8 (CDMA)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone10,4"])  deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 8";               //iPhone 8 (GSM)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone10,2"])  deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 8 Plus";          //iPhone 8 Plus (CDMA)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone10,5"])  deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone 8 Plus";          //iPhone 8 Plus (GSM)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone10,3"])  deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone X";               //iPhone X (CDMA)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPhone10,6"])  deviceFormattedName = @"iPhone X";               //iPhone X (GSM)

    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPod1,1"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPod Touch 1st Gen";     //iPod Touch 1G
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPod2,1"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPod Touch 2nd Gen";     //iPod Touch 2G
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPod3,1"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPod Touch 3rd Gen";     //iPod Touch 3G
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPod4,1"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPod Touch 4th Gen";     //iPod Touch 4G
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPod5,1"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPod Touch 5th Gen";     //iPod Touch 5G
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPod7,1"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPod Touch 6th Gen";     //iPod Touch 6G

    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad1,1"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad 1";                 //iPad Wifi
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad1,2"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad 1";                 //iPad 3G
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,1"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad 2";                 //iPad 2 (WiFi)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,2"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad 2";                 //iPad 2 (GSM)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,3"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad 2";                 //iPad 2 (CDMA)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,4"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad 2";                 //iPad 2 (WiFi)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,5"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Mini";              //iPad Mini (WiFi)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,6"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Mini";              //iPad Mini (GSM)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad2,7"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Mini";              //iPad Mini (GSM+CDMA)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,1"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad 3";                 //iPad 3 (WiFi)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,2"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad 3";                 //iPad 3 (GSM+CDMA)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,3"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad 3";                 //iPad 3 (GSM)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,4"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad 4";                 //iPad 4 (WiFi)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,5"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad 4";                 //iPad 4 (GSM)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad3,6"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad 4";                 //iPad 4 (GSM+CDMA)
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad4,1"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Air";               //iPad Air A1474
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad4,2"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Air";               //iPad Air A1475
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad4,3"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Air";               //iPad Air A1476
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad4,4"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Mini";              //iPad Mini 2 A1489
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad4,5"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Mini";              //iPad Mini 2 A1490
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad4,6"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Mini";              //iPad Mini 2 A1491
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad4,7"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Mini";              //iPad Mini 3 A1599
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad4,8"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Mini";              //iPad Mini 3 A1600
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad4,9"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Mini";              //iPad Mini 3 A1601
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad5,1"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Mini";              //iPad Mini 4 A1538
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad5,2"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Mini";              //iPad Mini 4 A1550
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad5,3"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Air";               //iPad Air 2 A1566
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad5,4"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Air";               //iPad Air 2 A1567
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad6,7"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Pro 12.9\"";          //iPad Pro 12.9"
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"iPad6,4"])     deviceFormattedName = @"iPad Pro 9.7\"";           //iPad Pro 9.7"

    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"i386"])        deviceFormattedName = @"Simulator";              //Simulator
    else if ([deviceOriginalName isEqualToString:@"x86_64"])      deviceFormattedName = @"Simulator";              //Simulator

    return deviceFormattedName;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#import <sys/utsname.h>

struct utsname systemInfo;
uname(&systemInfo);
NSString *deviceModel = [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

*deviceModel* contains device type. For example:

iPhone5,1 for iPhone 5 (model A1428)

iPhone5,2 for iPhone 5 (model A1429)

iPhone5,3 for iPhone 5c (model A1456, A1532)

iPhone5,4 for iPhone 5c (model A1507, A1516, A1526, A1529)

iPhone6,1 for iPhone 5s (model A1433, A1533)

iPhone6,2 for iPhone 5s (model A1457, A1518, A1528, A1530)